# Linq DataContext class not accessible in my MVC after I save the dbml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I just downloaded MVC and I am going through a tutorial.  Everything goes fine until I try to declare a DataContext object.

My dbml is named **db.dbml** (tried another on named test.dbml) and when I try this:

```
public dbDataContext db = new dbDataContext();
```

I get:

> The type or namespace name
>   'dbDataContext' could not be found ...

Am I missing something?  In webforms this is all I had to do, and in the tutorial that is all that is shown.  I downloaded the newest MVC today...

Thank you.

**EDIT: I am using VS2008 SP1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sp1 bug if you are using partial classes, see the following and work-arounds:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=361577

Answer (score 1):

A few quick questiosn: Is the name of your data context "dbDataContext"?... also, is it in a namespace? (do you have that namespace referenced).

Another question... is this a runtime error, or a compiletime error?

Answer (score 0):

try to add context to the namespace {ProjectName}.Models...

because the models are stored in the models namespace.. try to check if you have include the namespace in your current context..

Answer (score -1):

once you add the class just build the solution.you ll find your classes in the list